# How to check if an list of attributes contains a contains specific value in Hugo JS

Tags: javascript, hugo

i tried to add **multi-author support** to my theme and blog. Multi-author in this case means one post can be written by multiple authors and the posts are listed on each of the authors page.

Adding further authors to the "auhtor"-Attribute of the theme doesnt work because it seems it doesnt display values of list. Only single values and i can´t figure out how to change this.

Therefore we created the workaround, to add a NEW attribute "auhtor**s**" in case we need to display several authors. The entry of the Markdown-File looks either like this:

```
author: 1Author
```

or like this:

```
authors: 
  - 1Author
  - 2Author
```

In the code we checked if the author**s**-attribute is set (and therefore need to adapt the function to lists) or if we can use the normal author-function.

This works fine so far but we encountered problems when we tried to display the posts written by the author on the author page.The following function does not work with lists i suppose.

```
{{ range where site.RegularPages "Params.authors" "in" "$.Title"}}
      {{ .Render "post" }}
{{end}}
```

I have tried several other variants but could not make it to display the blog post which **contains** the attribute of authors which matches the sites title (the author name).

I am sure, there is only one little thing I am missing here but since i am quiet new to this field i would appreciate some insights.

**---- Update:**

the documentation of intersect and getTerms did not help, or at least i could not find a solution there.

However, logically the following should work but it doesnt:
´

```
  {{ $authorsSet := where site.RegularPages ".Params.authors" "ne" nil }} <!--check if authors set--> 
    
    {{ range $authorsSet}}
      {{$postauthors :=delimit .Params.authors ", " }} <!--gets the string of an array, removes the [] -->
        {{if in  $postauthors "$.Title"}} <!--checks if name of author matches the page-title -->
          {{ .Render "post-list" }}
        {{end}}
    {{end}}
```

´

the output of `$.Title` is `Autor Name1` and `$postauthors` is `Author Name1, Author Name2`.

But still i could not render those post where the author names matches the site title.

Could you tell, why the "in"-function does not work?

Hope anyone can help. Thank you guys!
Vincent

Comment: Looks you're trying to match with "$.Title". Is the author name supposed to be in the Title variable? I would expect you want to match on `.Params.authors`. In my experience the best operator for working with collections like this is "intersect". Official example: https://gohugo.io/functions/where/#use-where-with-intersect

Comment: .GetTerms is what you want  - see docs

Comment: @BrianWagner yes the title of the authors page is the authors name. 

Unfortunately if try to match on `.Params.authors` it does not work because the output is "[name author1] [name author2]" and not "name author1". 

This is the main problem. To to this i cant use the original line which was `{{ range where site.RegularPages "Params.author" .Title}}`

Comment: I think the only piece missing for "intersect" to work is putting the page title (author's name) inside a slice. This works for me `{{ $pages := where site.RegularPages "Params.authors" "intersect" (slice $pageTitle) }}`. Another option would be to get all pages, range over all the pages, and use an `if in .Params.authors $pageTitle` statement to check if the titles match, then print the content. Note I am setting the `$pageTitle` variable outside this block to ensure it's set properly.

Comment: Thank you so much @BrianWagner. This worked exactly as intended.

The slice on the $pagetitle was my missing part in the end. 

Thanks again for the support!